# Copy Hydro (ROS-Comm) from another drive

Tags: ros, roshydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to reinstall my Ubuntu 13.10 but am able to recover files from the previous hard disk.  Thus I am trying to set-up my ROS Hydro install (ROS-Comm compiled from source) by copying files across due to a poor internet connection.  So far it seems to be working with some exceptions.
I can create new workspaces,  create packages, catkin_make packages, use `roscore`, run publishers and subscribers.  But what is not working is the preprocessor that converts `msg` and `svr` files into C++ header files (and probably same problem with Python/Lisp files).

From [Installing on Ubuntu from source](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source), I performed the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update

    copied my ros_catkin_ws

copied entries from my old .bashrc to current one (including necessary environment variables):
  source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
    
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y

Tests:
  roscore   (WORKED)
  rostopic list (WORKED)
  catkin_make (WORKED)
  ran my publisher/subscriber nodes (WORKED)
```

I'm wondering how the preprocessing takes place, and hence what I need to fix up.  Could anyone please elaborate on this or point me to a reference I can read up.

Thanks, Nap.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131421/copy-hydro-(ros-comm)-from-another-drive/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To fix the MSG and SRV files preprocessing problem, I simply deleted the BUILD and DEVEL folders in the workspace and executed `catkin_make` again.  Running `catkin_make clean` was not enough to fix this problem.

---

Originally posted by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) with karma: 302 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-02-25**:
I would like to mark this answer as the correct one, but I don't have enough rep points. :(

I haven't tested all the tools yet, but everything I normally use is working fine.